# "AttributeError: unknown.CC " while trying to parse emails in MS outlook 2010 with python

Tags: python-3.x, win32com

I am trying parse emails in MS outlook 2010 under specific outlook mailbox with help of python. After reading few email without any issues, it suddenly gives error  **"AttributeError: unknown.CC"**

I tried to investigate the reason but failed to understand. Thus request you to please help.

```
import win32com.client as client

outlook=client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

namespace=outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

Der=namespace.Folders['Drive']

Dinbox=Der.Folders['Inbox']

for message in Dinbox.Items:
    if message.Categories =="":
        if "xyz" in message.CC or "xyz" in message.To :
            message.Categories="xyz"
```

Below is the error which i encounter :

```
Error: AttributeError: <unknown>.CC

C:\Users\SSS\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py, line 527,in __getattr__
            
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" %(self._username_,attr))

AttributeError: unknown.CC
```

Answer (score 0):

And the solution was very simple...i just had to ignore  items which wasn't email while parsing.